# Delphi XE6, Load rtf from Database

Tags: database, delphi, load, rtf, delphi-xe6

How can I convert a string to RTF format read from the database?
When  read, in the richedit appears the string with tag : /par {ansistring.......

I tried using this code but the result is the same.

```
    rtfString:= set1.fieldbyname('corpo_rtf').asansistring;
    stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    stream.Clear;
    stream.Write(PAnsiChar(rtfString)^, Length(rtfString));
    stream.Position := 0;
    corpo.PlainText := False;
    corpo.Lines.LoadFromStream(stream);
    stream.Free;
```

Comment: OK, i correct it but now whene i execute this istruction : 
appoggio.fieldbyname('corpo_rtf').asansistring:=rtfstring;

delphi exit from function.  I think that the end caracter is the problem. Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine if the content of the memory stream is valid RTF. Ergo, that cannot be the case.

You need to dig deeper into the actual content of the memory stream. Write it out to a text file with .rtf extension. Try to load it with Wordpad. See what happens. You should see the same as your Delphi application displays.

So, where could this be going wrong? Some possible causes include:

- The data in the database is not valid RTF.
- There are some undesired text conversions being performed. We assume that `rtfString` is of type `AnsiString`. Is it?

Comment: OK, i correct it but now whene i execute this istruction : appoggio.fieldbyname('corpo_rtf').asansistring:=rtfstring; delphi exit from function. I think that the end caracter is the problem. Have you any idea?

Comment: There's not enough information for me to comment. I'm just trying to answer the question you asked with the facts you presented.